# Testing if slopes differ using data with different uncertainties?

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, uncertainty

I have two data sets that each have the following form:

```
 x       y sigma
13 1495.00  0.07
15 1700.91  0.09
...
```

basically where $x$ and $y$ are given, but also the uncertainty of $y$, denoted $\sigma$, is different for each point. The uncertainties reported are claimed to be the "68% credible region" around $y$.

I want to know whether the slope of the linear regression between $x$ and $y$ differs between the two data sets. It's easy enough for me to just do (in R)

```
model1 <- lm(data1$y ~ data$x)
slope1 <- coef(model1)[2]
d_slope1 <- summary(model1)$coefficients[2,2]
```

and the same for `data2` and then check to see if they are outside of each other's uncertainty. But this ignores the information of $\sigma$. How can I incorporate $\sigma$ into my calculations?

My idea has been to add `rnrom(nrow(data), 0, sigma)` to `y` some large number of times and calculate the average standard error of the slope over all of these simulated noise additions, something like:

```
out <- rep(0, 1000)
for (ii in 1:1000) {
    noisy_y <- data1$y + rnrom(nrow(data1), 0, sigma)
    out[ii] <- summary(lm(noisy_y ~ data1$x))$coefficients[2,2]
}
better_d_slope1 <- mean(out)
```

Is this the correct way to do it?

Additional complication: I'm actually doing a weighted fit, where the weights come from another data set. I would think that one would normally set the weights to be $1/\sigma$, but I already have weights. (Maybe I should multiply them?)

Comment: Multiplication is correct .